# How can i get codeigniter session database blob value?

Tags: codeigniter, session, blob

With `Codeigniter` `session`.
I have created the **ci_session** table.
In this table I save `session` datas in the `blob` datatype.

```
$sess_data= array(
        'logged_in' => TRUE
);
$this->session->set_userdata($sess_data);
```

For count all online users, I need to get `logged_in==1` value in `blob` datatype.

For example, `user 1` is logged in with Chrome web browser. `User2` is logged in with Mozilla. In the `database` there are 2 sessions with the different session id.

How can i get this **all** `logged_in==1` values in this `ci_session table`?
**This is my model function.**
Please help me the fill where place in this function?

```
public function count_online_users(){
$this->db->select('*');
$this->db->from('ci_session');
$this->db->where(...........);
$query = $this->db->get()->num_rows();
return $query;
}
```

Comment: and you cannot count logged in users from ci_session table

Answer (score 0):

> Check this this method you have to follow

First you have to update `logged_in = 1` in your `users` table as your defined name

after you get number of users are `logged_in`

```
// Update user in to call this function 
$data = array(
                 'logged_in' => '1'
             );
public function update_user($user_id, $data)
{
    $this->db->where('id',$user_id);
    $this->db->update('users',$data);
}

// After you get logged in user in total value
public function count_online_users()
{
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->from('users');
    $this->db->where('logged_in','1');
    $query = $this->db->get()->num_rows();
    return $query;
}
```

You can use javascript and asynchron request for update field. When you close the window, the handler of window.onunload is called

```
var unloadHandler = function(e){
    //here ajax request to close session
};
window.unload = unloadHandler;
```

To solve the problem of redirection, php side you can use a counter

```
class someController  extends Controller {
    public function methodWithRedirection(){
        $this->session->set_userdata('isRedirection', 1);
        //here you can redirect  
    }
}
class homeController extends Controller{
    public function closeConnection(){
        $this->load->library('session');
        if($this->session->userdata('isRedirection')!== 1){
            //destroy session
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You're suggesting the OP add a "logged_in" column to a "users" table? How do you propose keeping the column value valid in the case where the session expires or otherwise ends without the user explicitly logging off?

Comment: Is it possible to get array value in blob data?

Comment: @omurgokyar yes it is simply possible

Comment: i actually input and update logged_in=1 value in data column which is blob datatype. But when i try to get this array value in blob datatype i lived problems.   How can i get any array value in blob datatype in Codeigniter .

Comment: @ImBS
`CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS ci_sessions (
        id varchar(128) NOT NULL,
        ip_address varchar(45) NOT NULL,
        timestamp int(10) unsigned DEFAULT 0 NOT NULL,
        data blob NOT NULL,
        KEY cisociall_sessions_timestamp (timestamp)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 COLLATE=utf8_unicode_ci;
ALTER TABLE ci_sessions ADD PRIMARY KEY (id, ip_address);`

it is my table.